# Как удалить модель и все зависимости к ней?

Tags: php, laravel, activerecord, eloquent

Речь пойдет о Laravel и соотвественно Eloquent ORM

Есть модель пользователя User и модель друзей пользователя Friend. Между моделями существует отношение `belongsToMany()`

Как сделать, чтобы при удаление пользователя, удалялись и все его друзья, то есть все зависимости и отношения?

Я знаю, что можно переопределить метод delete(), можно написать на это удаление функцию, а как-то "из коробки" можно это сделать?

Знаю, что в `foreign` можно задать поведение `onDelete('cascade')`.

А если речь идет о `softDelete` модели, предполагая, что все зависимые модели тоже поддерживают `softDelete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В модели Laravel есть возможность определять действия на события с нужной вам сущностью.

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Friend');
    }

    // this is a recommended way to declare event handlers
    public static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($user) { // before delete() method call this
             $user->friends()->delete();
             // do the rest of the cleanup...
        });
    }
}
```

Тесть, когда будет удалятся User сработает boot метод deleting.
Если хотите знать больше https://habr.com/ru/post/354036/
Третий пункт как раз по вашей теме :)